# Spread list items evenly with equal padding (preferably without JavaScript)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an HTML/CSS only `<ul>` layout in which the `<li>` items are evenly spread over the available width, and the padding between `<a>` and `<li>` elements are all the same. Here's my HTML-code (not very exciting):

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2 with long name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

The result should look like this:

[image: the result]

The `x` of course represents the amount of padding, which is the same for every item in the list.

I tried to use `display: table`, but this doesn't give the desired result. When using `display: table` the spacing between the `<li>` items depends on the length of the text within the `<a>` element, so `x` is different for every element.

Since the available width and the amount of `<li>` items are variable, what is the best way to determine the value of `x`? I also also want `x` to have a maximum value of 100px, in this case the width of the `<ul>` isn't the same as the available width.

I presume this is possible with JavaScript, but since there's already a lot of JavaScript on the page I don't want to use anymore JavaScript than necessary. So I prefer a CSS/HTML only solution.

Comment: So what do you expect to happen if the middle item in your example had less text? would the total width of the container be less than a 100%? or would `x` increase for all 3 items?

Comment: In that case `x` would increase for all three items. If `x` is greater than 100px, than `x` is 100px.

Comment: If you want to do that with CSS alone then your best bet is `display: table` OR Flexbox which allows to manage space better but not exaclty what you want. Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/pf9PE/

Comment: Thanks, but indeed not exactly what I want. Your fiddle shows all the items in a vertical list, instead of a horizontal one. At lease in Safari 7.0, which I use at the moment.

Comment: Safari does not support the new syntax for flexbox yet. That fiddle was meant to be viewed in Chrome. Sorry should've clarified.

Comment: Hm, ok. I think I have to go with JavaScript then. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Stan could you share your Javascript that you used? I'm in the same boat as you

Comment: I answered with my JS

Answer (score 2):

Here's the JavaScript i'm using:

```
var containerWidth = $('ul').outerWidth();
var liWidthTotal = 0;

$('li').each(function() {
    liWidthTotal += $(this).outerWidth();
});

var padding = Math.round((containerWidth - liWidthTotal) / ($('.topNav > div > ul > li').length*2));

$('.li > a').each(function() {
    $(this).css('padding', '0px ' + padding + 'px');
});
```

I'm basically checking how much space is available to fill (width of `ul` - width of `li`) and spread that equally to all `A`-Tags as padding. Why to the a-tags? So your hover effekts fill the whole width of that element. You can also give it to the `LI`'s of course.

Of course you need to adjust your selectors in the jQuery call.
If you made your `LI`'s `inline-block` you should also either write them in one line or give them `float: left` to prevent white-space between them.
In my example your `UL` needs to fill the whole width (`display: block`).

Comment: Unfortunately JavaScript is the only way to go for now. This is the best answer. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: yeah i know. You should accept this as the right answer then :P

Answer (score 0):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2B4B/7/), you want to use `display:table-cell;` on the list items, and `display:table;` on the list element. On each list item then do `padding: 0 100px;`

CSS:

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}
ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}
li{
    border:1px solid red;
    padding:0 100px;
    text-align:center;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: wrong. More elements and the table is too wide. Lower the padding to `10px` and it's not equal padding anymore. This is not what OP is asking for.

Comment: @Sumit, I read 'the result should look like this' in the OPs question, followed by an image, to mean that's what the result should look like

Comment: but he clearly meant a general, flexible solution. That's what CSS & HTML is there for. Otherwise he could just use an image or static widths.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">bipin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">bipin kumar pal</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">pal</a></li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul{
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}
li{
    border:2px solid green;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
}
```

And see this link http://jsfiddle.net/bipin_kumar/t2B4B/5/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know how `display: table-cell` works, but the result is clearly different as the desired result, which is shown in the image of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I just edited the below fiddles to match your requiremens.Try this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/t2B4B/9/

CSS:

```
body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
}
ul{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
 display:table;
}
li{
 border:1px solid red;
 padding-left:20px;
 padding-right:20px;
 display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: @Sumit u asked padding thats why i wrote CSS for li with padding.Your actual requirement was to align text in the center which if i knew i would have done it that way.

Comment: No, the actual requirement of OP (not me), was to spread any number of `LI` to 100% while maintaining the same padding on all `LI` which means that padding needs to be flexible.